# What pieces of warm clothing can be obtained on Zeah?

Tags: oldschool-runescape

I'm working on getting to Wintertodt in the Twisted League, but I don't know what warm clothing I can get here. On my main I use the Santa outfit which obviously cannot be obtained on Zeah. What are my warm clothing options for the Twisted League?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Outside the obvious option of the [Pyromancer outfit](https://oldschool.runescape.wiki/w/Pyromancer_outfit) (which is obtained through Wintertodt itself), the only pieces of warm clothing that are available are the following:

- [Clue hunter garb](https://oldschool.runescape.wiki/w/Clue_hunter_garb), obtained by digging a particular tile in Shayzien
- [Staff of fire](https://oldschool.runescape.wiki/w/Staff_of_fire), purchased at Filamina's Wares in Arceuus (requires 20% Arceuus favour to purchase, only stocks 2 per world)
- [Lit bug lantern](https://oldschool.runescape.wiki/w/Bug_lantern), purchased from Konar quo Maten (requires 33 Slayer to equip)
- [Fire battlestaff](https://oldschool.runescape.wiki/w/Fire_battlestaff), dropped by various monsters including Fire Giants
- [Lava battlestaff](https://oldschool.runescape.wiki/w/Lava_battlestaff), dropped by various monsters including Deviant Spectres

No other pieces of warm clothing can be obtained.

Keep in mind that Wintertodt damage also scales with your HP. With sufficiently low HP, you can get away with just 1 piece of warm clothing and still only take 1 damage each time.

Comment: Looks like lava staves are also possible to get from Deviant and Repugnant spectres.  You can see this listed in the drop sources for a lava staff on [the Wiki](https://oldschool.runescape.wiki/w/Lava_battlestaff) (they have special Twisted League symbols next to it).  It also appears fire battle staves are dropped from different enemies as well.

Comment: @TimmyJim while I wrote this answer with 10 hp Wintertodt in mind, I'll add those to the list

Comment: As another point, if you chose the endurance relic, the 4x hp regen makes it almost impossible to die from the damage you take as well.